# How to interpret mixed models?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am a bit confused about how to interpret mixed-effects models. Here is an example of something that I currently have. When I show the visreg graph, it is only showing test/status as variables against my y-axis. So what is happening to age/gender here? Does it make sense to say that I am controlling for age/gender in this situation by only graphing test/status? If not, how can I model this so that I am controlling for age or gender?

```
fit <- lmer(value ~ status * test + age + gender + (1 | ID), data = temp)

visreg(fit, xvar = "test", by = "status")
```

Answer (score 0):

The regression model is indeed controlling for, or perhaps more appropriately, *adjusting for* age and gender in reporting the association between test and value, status and value, and the combination of test and status (test*status) and value. So the coefficients reported by `summary(fit)` are giving you exactly what you want. However, visreg itself does not appear to do this, according to the [documentation](https://pbreheny.github.io/visreg/mixed.html).

Your visreg code is asking for the [conditional effect](https://pbreheny.github.io/visreg/contrast.html) of test by status, which is reported to be the effect *conditional* on the median value of the continuous predictors or most populous category of a categorical predictor(s). You can instead request a contrast plot, which will give you the desired effect of test or subject, adjusting for the other variables in the regression. Worth noting, however, is that with mixed models, the random effects "drop out of a contrast plot." But I'm guessing that this is what you want rather than the conditional plot. To get the contrast plot, simply add `, type="contrast"` after `"status"`.